# What to do about "Please check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try to start monerod.exe manually." in the GUI

Tags: daemon, error-log

I want to create a local monero node however it always comes with this error, "Please check your wallet and daemon log for errors. You can also try to start monerod.exe manually."
What should I do?

Comment: What are you doing to face this error? What do you launch?

Answer (score 2):

This message tells you that the GUI failed to automatically run the monerod software. This softwere's logs might have more information about why it failed to start, and the GUI is telling you to check those logs. They're typically stored in ~/.bitmonero/bitmonero.log (at least on Linux and Mac).

You can also run monerod yourself, instead of relying of the GUI automatic system. If you don't change the defaults (eg, port), then the GUI will spot a running monerod and not try to run it automatically.

Answer (score -3):

Turn off AV, my Norton created the exact same error message but also quarantined my extracted files. I re-extracted Monero into a new directory with AV disabled. It is now working fine - Cybershield